# Simple Dependency Property and UserControl issues in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

My end goal is to expose the `Text` value of a `TextBox` that I have in a `UserControl`, from the `UserControl`'s call in XAML.

```
<my:UserControl SetCustomText="Blah blah this is variable">
```

would render the `UserControl` with that `TextBox`'s text filed in.

I've been working at it using various examples but I always end up with "The Property SetCustomText was not found in type UserControl"

Comment: please post code for the SetCustomText dependency property?

Comment: Are you sure its correct UserControl? I would not name your custom class same as something in WPF. Its confusing.

Answer (score 4):

Example of how you can do this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.UserControls.MyUserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             Name="control">
    <Grid>
        <!-- Text is being bound to outward representative property -->
        <TextBox Text="{Binding MyTextProperty, ElementName=control}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

```
public partial class MyUserControl1 : UserControl
{
    // The dependency property which will be accessible on the UserControl
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyTextProperty", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl1), new UIPropertyMetadata(String.Empty));
    public string MyTextProperty
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyTextPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyTextPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    public MyUserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

```
<uc:MyUserControl1 MyTextProperty="Text goes here"/>
```

Comment: And what if we have two textblocks on the user control?

Comment: @HamedZakeryMiab Then use two names and two dependency properties. How hard is that?