# Binding to a custom property in Xaml (Windows 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, c++-cx

I'm trying to set a custom attached property which I can bind to in Xaml. It works fine if I pass it plain strings:

MyProperties.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "pch.h"

namespace SimpleApp
{
    namespace WUX = Windows::UI::Xaml;

    public ref class MyProperties sealed : public WUX::DependencyObject
    {
    private:
        static WUX::DependencyProperty^ _MyValue;

    public:
        MyProperties::MyProperties();

        static property WUX::DependencyProperty^ MyValue
        {
            WUX::DependencyProperty^ get()
            {
                return _MyValue;
            }
        };
        static Platform::String^ GetMyValue(WUX::UIElement^ element);
        static void SetMyValue(WUX::UIElement^ element, Platform::String^ value);
    };
}
```

MyProperties.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "MyProperties.h"

using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace SimpleApp;

MyProperties::MyProperties()
{
};


DependencyProperty^ MyProperties::_MyValue = DependencyProperty::RegisterAttached(
    "MyValue", 
    Platform::String::typeid, 
    MyProperties::typeid,
    ref new PropertyMetadata(false)
    );

Platform::String^ MyProperties::GetMyValue(UIElement^ element)
{
    auto val = safe_cast<Platform::String^>(element->GetValue(_MyValue));
    return val;
}

void MyProperties::SetMyValue(UIElement^ element, Platform::String^ stringValue)
{
    element->SetValue(_MyValue, stringValue);
    OutputDebugString(L"It worked!");
    // Also do other stuff
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="SimpleApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SimpleApp"
    Width="525"
    >

    <Grid x:Name="_grid" Width="500" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_grid}">

        <TextBlock local:MyProperties.MyValue="Hello" Text="{Binding Width}" />

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

This works - the SetMyValue function executes with the parameter "Hello" passed to it.

When I try and use binding on the MyValue property, though, SetMyValue doesn't execute. I'm replacing the TextBlock with this in Xaml:

```
<TextBlock local:MyProperties.MyValue="{Binding Width}" Text="{Binding Width}" />
```

I am binding Text to Width as well just to be sure that it is, in general, working. Is there a magic declaration I have to make somewhere to persuade the property to be bindable?

NB [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956767/binding-to-custom-dependency-property-again) is asking something similar, but for WPF, and the asker didn't seem to have his problem solved anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think your binding is working. The fact that `SetMyValue` is not called also makes sense to me. WPF bypasses your property getter/setter, and uses the internal dependency property instead, for performance reasons(eg `SetMyValue` is not called).

If you are interested about the value changes, you need to explictly say so:

(random copy/paste)

```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterIDProperty = 
          DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
     FilterIDPropertyName,
     typeof(int),
     typeof(PeopleUserControl),
     new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, 
          FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, FilterIDChanged));
```

`FilterIDCHanged` will be called, once the dependency property changes. Also, notice that I passed the `BindsTwoWayByDefault` to dependency property, I don't remember 100% if that's needed, but this can also be the reason why binding doesn't work.